# Remove points and dashed line from respective legend item symbols and add space between them

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the data and code below how can I remove `geom_points` from `Average Precipitation` and `Average Mean Temperature` showing in the legend and the dashed line from the `Precipitation` symbol, and add white space between these legend symbols? And for some reason these legend items symbols show the dashed line as a dashed `+`.

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(year = 1980:2021, AvgTMean = c(46.6861236310086, 
45.9935321876897, 48.1700038729655, 46.4810115090517, 46.4829304907586, 
46.7485468749052, 47.6219529266638, 47.2361218780086, 47.2499555211466, 
47.5220451962069, 48.5570011928017, 48.3781107312672, 46.8573046128362, 
47.176300310069, 48.4485899941034, 47.4609176108276, 46.6484865289397, 
48.1642107206379, 48.1402675745948, 46.9259296469741, 47.0971184616466, 
46.9726183841638, 47.6723684868621, 47.5039107233534, 47.1155762179138, 
46.7073537729569, 47.0220951396465, 47.7124003840862, 47.3834037927155, 
47.1793288212414, 45.2688071177586, 47.9963270432845, 47.1814417165345, 
47.868863306069, 47.5397788474655, 49.6073711623448, 48.3243434869914, 
48.3742754506034, 48.1300366010172, 48.8198359721638, 48.8188162341724, 
48.1362190050517), year.1 = 1980:2021, AvgPpt = c(7.98047681617574, 
4.49794226223406, 4.9684832619452, 5.55716999365373, 4.57494083048695, 
5.14877823483309, 4.97444435545455, 4.22068948662692, 3.60726044275288, 
2.84911801980053, 4.21517699598155, 5.46851140458677, 4.52277085448576, 
4.64293974933608, 6.15600410764903, 5.875274014911, 4.87718798058995, 
5.8443990209339, 5.32429453784799, 5.74763654079229, 4.17193446127319, 
4.76059529730215, 4.16013977314758, 4.69800474088282, 3.72061294666274, 
5.29432854004791, 3.93882676214587, 4.43336743516705, 4.64442420697922, 
5.77322014781625, 5.20579882483319, 4.61210504742011, 5.74595928751707, 
4.42505010181327, 4.9249395747262, 4.47639288282123, 4.93601457652385, 
6.44108245535473, 5.15154468243163, 6.11707801937097, 8.82894831877217, 
5.03274669845953)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L
))
```

Code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = AvgTMean, y = AvgPpt)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Precipitation"), size = 2, shape = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(linetype = "LM"), se = T, color = "red")  + 
  xlab("Mean Temperature (\u00B0F)") +
  ylab("Average Precipitation (in)") +
  ggtitle("Precipation - Mean Temperature Correlation Scatterplot") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 2, name = NULL) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Average Precipitation" = "blue",
                                 "Average Mean Temperature" = "orange",
                                 "Precipitation" = "black"), name = "Legend") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.5), order = 1)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(AvgPpt), color = "Average Precipitation"),linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(AvgTMean), color = "Average Mean Temperature"),linetype = "dashed") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

1. Map "precipitation" to the `shape` aesthetic to give it a different entry in the legend
2. Add a `scale_shape_manual` to give the correct shape
3. Change the `key_glyph` for `geom_vline` to `draw_key_path` to remove the vertical component of the key glyph

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = AvgTMean, y = AvgPpt)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = "Precipitation"), size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(linetype = "LM"), se = T, color = "red")  + 
  xlab("Mean Temperature (\u00B0F)") +
  ylab("Average Precipitation (in)") +
  ggtitle("Precipation - Mean Temperature Correlation Scatterplot") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 2, name = NULL) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Average Precipitation" = "blue",
                                 "Average Mean Temperature" = "orange"), 
                      name = "Legend") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.5), order = 1)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(AvgPpt), 
                 color = "Average Precipitation"),
                 linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(AvgTMean), 
                 color = "Average Mean Temperature"),
                 linetype = "dashed", key_glyph = draw_key_path) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 1, name = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]